# c++ functor for deleting pointers seems to work

Tags: c++, pointers, functor

Elsewhere the following was suggested for a functor for deleting pointers in a vector

```
struct DeleteFromVector
{
    template <class T>
    void operator() ( T* ptr) const
    {
            delete ptr;
    }
};
```

to be called using

```
std::for_each(aVec.begin(), aVec.end(), DeleteFromVector());
```

I had written something similar (though originally without the clever moving of the template within the struct):

```
    struct DeleteObj 
    {
        template<typename ObjType>
        inline void operator() (ObjType obj)
        { 
            delete obj; 
            obj = NULL; 
        };
    };
```

Stepping through it in the debugger it seems to work, i.e. obj is recognized as a pointer and nothing crashes.

I'm a bit confused as to why both work, and would also like to hear opinions on the use of const and inline in these.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Note that `obj = NULL` only affects the local parameter. It has no influence on the argument. Also, nulling out pointers after deleting them is considered bad style, because it tends to hide design problems instead of solving them.

Comment: Also, take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/freeptrfnc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why do both templates work?*

In the first template, you pass an `Obj*` to a template method taking a `T*` so the compiler deduces that `T` is `Obj`.

In the second template, you pass an `Obj*` to a template method taking a `T` so the compiler deduces that `T` is `Obj*`.

---

*Use of `inline`*

The `inline` is redundant there, as member functions *defined* inside the class definition are implicitly `inline`.

---

*Use of `const`*

Functors should have their `operator()` declared `const`if possible . This is because it is illegal to pass a temporary by non-const reference. A call to `std::for_each(...,..., Functor());` may not compile unless `Functor` has an `operator(T)const`.

*This issue is muddied by the fact that the Microsoft compilers implement a non-standard extension allowing passing temporaries by non-const reference and enable this non-standard behaviour by default.*

Comment: Regarding your remark about `const`: most of the times (at least in the algorithms from the standard library), functors are passed by value, so the use of `const` is not that important. Moreover, one advantage of functors is that they can keep state between calls, so forbidding them to modify this state would be a bit silly. However, if the `operator()` does not modify the state, there is no point in not making it `const` (the more `const`, the better).

Comment: Selected as answer because it was the most clear (for my little mind) on why both work.  Thanks too on the explanation of why inline is redundant, I didn't know that.                                                                       In general, thanks to all for your time and effort.

Comment: @Luc Touraille: While maintaining state does work in many cases, it is not sanctioned by the standard. The number of times that the functor is copied is undefined, and that means that any operation that depends on the state left from previous operations might not work as expected. Summary: avoid maintaining state *in* the functor (you can maintain a pointer or reference in the functor to externally maintained state, and that's perfectly fine)

Comment: @David: Are you sure about that? About `for_each`, the standard says `Effects: Applies f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range [first, last), starting from first and proceeding to last-1. Returns: f.`, where `f` is the callable entity given as argument. Since `f` must be returned, I always assumed that the same instance would be used for each processing (or at least would be copied from the one previously used, with the last copy being returned). Otherwise, what is the point of returning `f`?

Comment: If I remember correctly (and I may not), the problem is that the standard doesn't specify how many times a functor is copied, which implies a functor must be copyable and, if passed as a temporary, must have a `const operator()` to be compatible with all conforming standard library implementations.

Comment: I think there are different requirements for different algorithms. In case of `for_each` the same functor instance must be used for the whole range.

Comment: @Luc Touraille: It was a general comment. The standard does not state how many copies of the functor can be performed in any of the algorithms. I cannot imagine a readon to copy in `for_each`, but some other algorithms do. For example, `remove_if` is implemented in terms of `find_if` and an extra loop, the predicate is passed to `remove_if`, copied to `find_if` and that copy discarded when `find_if` completes. That means that any state stored in the predicate while *finding* the first element will be lost. That is a different example, but the requirements in the standard are the same for both.

Comment: @David: Fair enough. However, I find the standard a bit confusing in this regard. For example, if we look at `transform` or `accumulate` requirements, we can see that the operation is required not to have any side effects. Why? If all algorithms are allowed to make any number of copies, thereby making side effects completely unpredictable, why does `transform` get a special treatment to disallow these side effects? When I'll find the time, I'll post a question about this; such exegegis does not really belong in comments :).

Comment: @Luc Touraille: The requirements in transform is on the input range(s), not on the functor. The actual spelling of the rule has changed from *Requires: op and binary_op shall not have any side effects.* in C++03 to a more explicit *Requires: op and binary_op shall not invalidate iterators or subranges, or modify elements in the ranges [first1,last1], [first2,first2 + (last1 - first1)], and [result,result + (last1 - first1)]* in C++0x. Whether the functor maintains state or not, whether it is copied one or more times is not stated in any of the two standards.

Comment: As a matter of fact the C++0x standard explicitly states in §25.1/10 *Unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy those function objects freely. Programmers for whom object identity is important should consider using a wrapper class that points to a noncopied implementation object such as reference_wrapper<T> (20.8.3), or some equivalent solution.*

Answer (score 3):

The first is to be preferred since it will only compile if the vector element type is a pointer. The second would compile if the vector element type is convertable to a non-void pointer, with presumably disasterous consequences.

Functors are normally declared const, doesn't often make a difference but it doesn't cost anything either.

Comment: You can't delete a non-pointer. The difference is in where you get the error.

Comment: @UncleBens: Even if the non-pointer has a conversion to a pointer? Are you saying delete is an exception to the normal rules?

Answer (score 2):

It works because `ObjType` is deduced to be `WhateverTypeYouHaveInYourVector *`. With the first solution, `T` is deduced to be `WhateverTypeYouHaveInYourVector`. The latter is better because it requires the argument to be a pointer, while in your solution, the argument can be anything, even something that is not deletable.

By the way, `obj = NULL` is useless because you take the parameter by value. Consequently, the pointer that will be set to null is the copy local to the function, not the one contained in the vector. You could take a reference to a pointer instead:

```
struct Deleter
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T * & ptr) const
    {
        delete ptr;
        ptr = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Even with a reference, you would only nullify the argument, and not any other copy of the pointer.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Obviously, yes. If the objects deleted are pointed to by many pointers accross the application, the best thing to do is to start using some smart pointers such as `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`.

Comment: re: ptr = NULL and pass by copy <deep sigh>

Comment: I guess it is the magic of it deducing the type when it is not being explicitly declared that I'm grappling with.  It has been a looooong time since I've worked with templates and this is my first foray into functors.

Answer (score 2):

- Why both work: If you call `operator()(U*)`, the first one matches `T = U`, the second one matches `ObjType = U*`.
- `const`: that just says that you're not modifying any members, but since your structs are empty, this makes no difference. Some algorithms may take their functors as const and hence allow only access to constant member functions (but not in `for_each`). In any event, your member function might as well be static, since the there's no state.
- inlining is just a compiler hint; chances are that construction would be inlined no matter what. Member definitions inside class definitions are implicitly inline anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Both work because both properly deduce the template parameter, just in one case it is a pointer, in the other it is the type that is being pointed to, because the signature already contains the `*`

inline is redundant here, as the function is inline already. Also setting the `obj = NULL` is useless since it sets only your local copy of the pointer to 0, not -- as was probably 
intended -- the entry in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

The second example may not work, because you did not make a pointer out of it:

```
inline void operator() (ObjType* obj)
```

This should work, just as the upper example.

The `inline` is a compiler optimization **suggestion** to completely copy the function to every place it is called.

The `const` keyword has many uses, depending on where you use it. In your case (in the first example) it means, that the class or object on which the method is called shall not alter and can be used in `const` contexts.